# ItemSource from XML file in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, telerik

I'm trying to bind the Telerik `RadJumpList` to a XML file that is stored in IsolatedStorage. Some of my code is below, but It doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
public IEnumerable<Phones> GetSavedData()
{
IEnumerable<Phones> phoneList = new List<Phones>();

try
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        string offlineData = Path.Combine("WPTracker", "Offline");
        string offlineDataFile = Path.Combine(offlineData, "phones.xml");
        IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(offlineDataFile, FileMode.Open);

        if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(offlineDataFile))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(isoFileStream))
            {
                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Phones>));
                List<Phones> phones = deserializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as List<Phones>;

                phones.Sort(
                    new Comparison<Phones>((Phones p1, Phones p2) =>
                    {
                        return p1.FullName.CompareTo(p2.FullName);
                    }));

                this.radJumpList1.ItemsSource = phones;

                return phones;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var update = new UpdateDatabase();
            update.UpdateData();

            GetSavedData();
        }
    }
}
catch (IsolatedStorageException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error retireving the data from Isolated Storage.", "The subscriber you are trying to reach can not be located.", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}

return phoneList;           
}
```

I think it has something to do with the reading of the XML file from IsolatedStorage because I get this error:

`[ExceptionMessage]:[There is an error in XML document (1, 2).]
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at WPTracker.ViewModels.Phones.PhoneMainView.GetSavedData()
   at WPTracker.ViewModels.Phones.PhoneMainView.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedToX(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator, IPhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, IPhoneApplicationPage newContentPage)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)]`

If needed, I can attach a copy of the XML file. It is basically a table from Azure Mobile Services.

### Update

Here is a link to some of my code (zip file)

- `UpdateXML.cs` is what I use to download the data from Azure and then save it into a XML file.
- `PhoneMainView` is where the `Phones` class is defined and where the `GetSavedData` code is
- `phones.xml` is the XML file from `UpdateXML.cs`

[SkyDrive ZIP File](http://sdrv.ms/16le2Pr)

Comment: It seems like your XML file if broken or your `Phone` class just doesn't match it. Can we see both the file and the `Phone` class?

Comment: @Harush I updated my post with the requested files.